# Return days between nodes in Neo4j 3.0

Tags: foreach, neo4j

I have a DB that has incidents.

Each incident has a relationship to a day

```
(i:Incident)-[:on]->(d:Day)
```

Each day has a relationship to the NEXT day

```
(d:Day {date:20160311})-[:NEXT]->(d1:Day {date:20160312})
```

I can get the list of Days that all incidents for a particular Item happend.

```
match (i:Incident)-[:involved]->(m:Model {name:'x.24 BETA'})
match (i)-[:on]-(d:Day)
```

and I can order the days by date

```
with i,d
order by d.date 
with collect (d) as days  
return days
```

what I am trying generate is a report that would list the date and the number of days between this incident and the next incident.

I thought If I had a collection I do a `FOREACH` over it and use `length()` to get the days between incidents.
Like So:

```
match p=(d1:Day {date:'20150813'})-[r:NEXT*]-> (d2:Day {date:'20160406'}) 
return length(p)
```

Of course, you cannot `MATCH` in a `FOREACH`.
Can anyone suggest a viable alternative approach?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this example dataset:

```
CREATE (day1:Day {date:'2015-01-01'}),
       (day2:Day {date:'2015-01-02'}),
       (day3:Day {date:'2015-01-03'}),
       (day4:Day {date:'2015-01-04'}),
       (day5:Day {date:'2015-01-05'}),
       (day1)-[:NEXT]->(day2)-[:NEXT]->(day3)-[:NEXT]->(day4)-[:NEXT]->(day5),
       (i1:Incident {id:1}),
       (i2:Incident {id:2}),
       (i3:Incident {id:3}),
       (i1)-[:ON]->(day1),
       (i2)-[:ON]->(day4),
       (i3)-[:ON]->(day5);
```

This looks like:

[image]

My understanding is that you'd want to see that for incident 1, it was 3 days until the next incident and for incident 2 it was 1 day until the next incident. Incident 3 wouldn't be returned because there has not been a next incident yet.

First I'd get all the days that have incidents and order by the date. Bring those days into a collection and the find the path length of each consecutive pair of elements (days) in that collection.

```
MATCH (:Incident)-[:ON]->(day:Day)
WITH day 
ORDER BY day.date
WITH collect(day) AS days
UNWIND range(1, size(days) - 1) AS idx
WITH days[idx - 1] AS from, days[idx] AS to
MATCH (i:Incident)-[:ON]->(from)
MATCH x = shortestPath((from)-[:NEXT*]->(to))
RETURN i.id AS incident, 
       from.date AS date,
       length(x) AS days_til_next_incident
ORDER BY i.id;
```

This returns:

[image]

Comment: Wow. That is exactly what I am looking for. Your explanation of the approach is very helpful and I will definitely do more research on UNWIND.  Thank you very much.